# PHP-SQL-Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, sql

This code is giveing me this error : Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

```
$fields[':email']=$_GET["email"];
$fields[':password']=$_GET["password"];
$fields[':telefono']=$_GET["telefono"];
$fields[':old_email']=$_GET["old_email"];
$fields[':isAdmin']=0;
$qry.="UPDATE utente SET Email:=email, Password:=password ,Telefono:=telefono, isAdmin=:isAdmin WHERE Email=:old_email";
$sth=$CONNESSIONE->prepare($qry);
$sth->execute($fields);
```

the var_dump of fields prints this

array(5) { [":email"]=> string(5) "test2" [":password"]=> string(1) "b" [":telefono"]=> string(7) "0415600" [":old_email"]=> string(4) "test" [":isAdmin"]=> int(0) }

and my table is this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `utente` (
  `Email` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `isAdmin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `Email` (`Email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this

```
$qry.="Email:=email, Password:=password ,Telefono:=telefono, isAdmin=:isAdmin WHERE Email=:old_email";
```

to

```
$qry.="Email=:email, Password=:password ,Telefono=:telefono, isAdmin=:isAdmin WHERE Email=:old_email";
```

You mistyped `:` before `=`